# Removing random strings of characters from the start of file names using Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, rename, file-rename

i have a few hundred files that i wish to rename

All have random strings at the start of the file name, but all have a constant in this example the word "File"

So how would i get from this

```
huhukifauduigui9983hodhohhh File 01 [145dde].ext
ljdwidnjncjbbbjbk File 55 [wniw].ext
wdwjbnkjbkjbiuiuiubi File 24 [wdwxxx].ext
plxwjijiwi File 14 [wddbb].ext
```

to this

```
File 01 [145dde].ext
File 55 [wniw].ext
File 24 [wdwxxx].ext
File 14 [wddbb].ext
```

Thank you in advance

The only thing i can think of is a powershell command but only really know how to replace specific strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), PowerShell's [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based string-replacement operator:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ext |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^.*\b(?=File)' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Regex `^.*\b(?=File)` matches any number (`*`) of characters (`.`) (possibly none) at the *start* of the file name (`^`) up to, but not including (due to use of a lookahead assertion, `(?=…)`) the word `File`, which must occur at a word boundary (`\b`).
For a more detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/mUDVAN/1).

Since no replacement operand is given, the *empty string* is implied resulting in the effective removal of the matching part.

Note that if a given file's name doesn't match the pattern, its name will be kept as-is.

Also note the use of a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) with [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item)'s `-NewName` parameter in order to *dynamically* determine the new file name based on each file-info object emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)